# Finding PHP URL

Tags: c#, regex, url

I've made a Regex to find any URL on site, which uses PHP:

```
Reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("((http|https)://([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,}[/]?))?[/]?([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,}[.](php|html))((/[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,}){1,}[/]?){0,}([?]([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}=[a-zA-Z0-9\"><();/.,]{1,}&?){1,})?");
```

Is this code optimal, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 7):

Using regex to match a URI is never a good solution... as you have discovered, you now have **two** problems (the base problem, and the regex problem).

In this case, you should use the language features to help you.... (*bear in mind I am a Java person, so I may have some syntax errors*)....

```
try {
    Uri uri = new Uri(stringvalue);
    // use your favourite C# function to check the localpath of the URI...
    if (uri.LocalPath.EndsWith("php") {
       // it **may** be a php page
    }
} catch (UriFormatException e) {
    // this is **not** a php page
}
```

Look!!! No potential regex problems... because [using a regex to match a URI is nearly impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."* - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: @Max - thanks, I was lazy and did not dig up the reference. FWIW, I love regex, it's like a really nice hammer... but not every problem is a nail.